# How to assign the INT value from MySQL database to Visual Studio Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Here is my code tho the 'money' as you can see it is in string value. I don't know how  to let the visual studio read it as int value but in the schema that I created it is set in int value. This is for my project:

```
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT Id, User_Name, password, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, age, gender, email, contact, money FROM bank.accounts WHERE User_Name ='" + txtBoxUName.Text + "' AND password ='" + txtBoxPass.Text + "'";

MySqlDataReader row;

row = con.ExecuteReader(query);

if (row.HasRows)             
{        
    while (row.Read())                    
   {                             
       id = row["Id"].ToString();                         
       uname = row["User_Name"].ToString();                         
       password = row["password"].ToString();                         
       fname = row["First_Name"].ToString();                         
       lname = row["Last_Name"].ToString();                         
       mname = row["Middle_Name"].ToString();                            
       age = row["age"].ToString();                         
       gender = row["gender"].ToString();                          
       email = row["email"].ToString();                        
       contact = row["contact"].ToString();                     
       money = row["money"].ToString();                  
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Data found! Welcome " + fname + "!");                                         
    this.Hide();
    Account acc = new Account();            
    acc.Show();
}                
else                   
{                       
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}
```

Comment: `row.GetInt32(columnNumber)` would be a way to get an integer type

Comment: and it  is also a good idea to start on **prepared statements** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html code gets vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Another way is to covert to string to int. `int m = Convert.ToInt32(row["money"]);`